# Horizontal accordion using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a horizontal accordion using jQuery. The code works fine, but I just want to know if my approach is correct and if there are any improvements I could make to the existing code.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("ul li").children(".Acc_Content").animate({ width: '0px' },{ duration: 1000, queue: false }).addClass("remove");
$(".Acc_Content").first().animate({ width: '600px' }, { duration: 1000, queue: false }).removeClass("remove").addClass("add");
$(".Acc_Name").click(function () {
$(".Acc_Content").animate({ width: '0px' }, { duration: 1000, queue: false }).removeClass("add").addClass("remove");
$(this).next(".Acc_Content").animate({ width: '600px' }, { duration: 1000, queue: false }).removeClass("remove").addClass("add");
});
});
```

```css
body{font-family: Arial;}
ul{list-style: none;}
.Acc_Name{background-color: #808080;color: white;border:1px solid #000;margin:0px 1px;height:150px;width:30px;float:left;}
.Acc_Name span{margin:5px;float:left;line-height:20px;font-weight:bold;   
-moz-transform:rotate(270deg); 
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg)}
.Acc_Content{float:left;height:150px;border:1px solid #000;}
.add{display:block;}
.remove{display:none;}
p{margin: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="Acc_Name">
    <span>One</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Acc_Content"><p>Hello Test1</p></div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="Acc_Name">
    <span>Two</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Acc_Content"><p>Hello Test2</p></div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="Acc_Name">
    <span>Three</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Acc_Content"><p>Hello Test3</p></div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="Acc_Name">
    <span>Four</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Acc_Content"><p>Hello Test4</p></div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, your JS and CSS could do some indenting. It's barely readable.

Now, seeing that you use transforms and you use a 2.x.x version of jQuery, I can assume you're targeting a modern browser. Instead of using jQuery's `animate`, you can use CSS transitions on `width` instead. Trigger your accordion by adding and removing classes that change the value of `width`. Aside from lesser JS, CSS animations are mostly hardware accelerated. This, in simple terms, mean smoother animations.

If you have the luxury of a build step, I suggest offloading the task of adding prefixes to your CSS to a task runner. Grunt or Gulp, with Autoprefixer should be able to help you.

Additionally, I would recommend being uniform with CSS colors. If you write hex most of the time, make sure they're all in hex and avoid color names. If you mostly do 6-digit hex, then write in 6-digit hex and avoid the 3 digit ones. If you're worried about file size, let a compressor task like cssmin do it for you.